# How to do artifical intelligence "upscaling" to a pixelated or smeared image?

Tags: gimp, png, free, zoom, artificial-intelligence

I have used the following Mermaid editor to create the following Mermaid chart as a PNG image by using the following Mermaid code.

### Mermaid editor

https://mermaid.live

### Mermaid chart

[image]

### Mermaid code

```
flowchart TD
    1[aaaaa]
    1 --> 2[bbbbb]
    2 --> A1[ccccc] 
    2 --> A2[ddddd]
    2 --> A3[eeeee]
    2 --> A4[fffff]
    A2 --> A[hhhhh]
    A1 & A2 --> 5[iiiii]
    5 & A4 --> A5[jjjjj]
    5 --> 6[kkkkk]
    6 --> 7[lllll]
    8 --> 9[mmmmm]
    X[nnnnn] --> 11
    7 --> 10[ooooo] & 11[ppppp] & 12[qqqqq] & 14[rrrrr]
    XX[sssss]
    12 & XX --> B[ttttt]
    11 & 12 & 9 --> 13[uuuuu]
    11 & XX --> 15[vvvvv]
    10 & 15 --> 16[wwwww]
    13 --> 17[xxxxx]
    17 --> 18[yyyyy] & 19[zzzzz] & 20[11111] & 21[22222]
    15 & 18 & 21 --> C1[33333]
    C1 --> C2[44444]
    C2 & 16 --> C2_1[55555]
    XXX[66666] & C2 --> C3[77777]
    C3 --> C4[88888]
    C4 --> C2_1
    C4 ---> C5[99999] & C6[a1a1a1a1a1]
    A4 & 16 & C3 --> XXXX[a2a2a2a2a2]
    B & XX & XXXX & 16 & C4 --> I1[a3a3a3a3a3]
    I1 --> I2[a4a4a4a4a4] & I3[a5a5a5a5a5]
    I2 --> I2_2[a6a6a6a6a6]
    I2 --> I2_1[a7a7a7a7a7]
    I2_2 --> I3 & I5
    I3 --> I4[a8a8a8a8a8] --> I5[a9a9a9a9a9]
    I3 --> I6[b1b1b1b1b1] --> I7[b2b2b2b2b2]
    17 & C1 & C5 & C6 --> C7[b3b3b3b3b3]
    15 --> ZZ[b4b4b4b4b4] & I2 --> I8
    I2 & I6 --> I8[b5b5b5b5b5]
    I2 --> I9[b6b6b6b6b6]
    I7 --> E[b7b7b7b7b7]
    17 & C5 & C7 --> C8[b8b8b8b8b8]
    C7 --> C9[b9b9b9b9b9]
    C8 & 19 --> R1[c1c1c1c1c1]
```

### My problem

My problem is that the above PNG image looks pixelated or smeared when zooming in.

### My question

How to solve my problem?
Perhaps, how to do artifical intelligence "upscaling" to a pixelated or smeared image? Preferably with a free or open source tool?
I can export the chart to SVG instead of PNG but I need it in PNG due to technical reasons outside the scope of this QA session.

---

### An update about the Inkscape approach in Rafael's answer

In an answer below it was suggested to use Inkscape to `export as PNG at a higher resolution`, but how to actually do this with Inkscape?

Moreover, when I open the SVG file in Inkscape I get a strange White rectangle and several Black rectangles:

[image]

---

### An update about the PNG export approach in Rafael's answer

The screenshot in the answer by Rafael may confuse you (not intentionally of course) because it doesn't tell you which of the two "PNG" buttons you should click; you can mistakenly click the first one instead the second one and get the wrong PNG output:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Do you know that you can change the size of the PNG when downloading it. Just make the size bigger in pixels, and you will get a higher resolution image. here's [one that is 5000px x 5000px](https://imgur.com/rk47nFT) - that's a 25MP image. Should be good enough for printing. Also note that you shouldn't really zoom in with raster images anyway. They're best viewed at 100% (1:1)

Comment: The setting is in the Mermaid actions panel. [See screenshot](https://imgur.com/DAnc7mq). I chose 5000px because that makes a high resolution image. The more pixels, the higher the resolution.  I don't know if there is an upper limit, but a 25 megapixel image is good enough for printing.  5000x5000=25000px (25 megapixels).

Comment: I don't need to add an answer. I see that Rafael has already suggested you output a larger PNG image directly. It's the correct answer.

Comment: It looks like you can only choose either "width" or "height". It doesn't allow you to choose both independently because that would alter the aspect ratio (which is not a good idea). I tried one at 7000px wide. That works too.

Comment: yes it adds more white space, but it's still a higher resolution image. If there is too much white space you could just crop the image in an image editor like GIMP or Photoshop. Here's [a huge one](https://i.imgur.com/eeqeyLO.png) I created by setting the size to 7000px wide, and then  I just cropped it in GIMP.

Comment: @BillyKerr hehe this can be an answer in itself and I didn't know that ! :))) I have already accepted Rafael's answer but please go through the last update in the question to know what confused me from Rafael's screenshot.

Comment: To be honest, I think Rafaels answer is good enough.  Normally you would be able to open an SVG in Inkscape, but the SVG output from Merrmaid actually contains HTML which Inkscape can't understand. It's not really a proper SVG file. That's why it's not opening properly in Inkscape.  This isn't Inkscapes fault though, the problem lies with Mermaid.

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

The program in question is very limited. The SVG is somehow buggy (at least incompatible with other software). And the generated images are inconsistent between the export buttons.

But let me recap the options. (This is a kinda of documentation that the developer of the application should have done!)

### PNG

The two buttons for PNG and the two for SVG do the same. Alow you to download the image, but use for some reason a different internal algorithm therefore output. **The first icon used means download** and **the second means open in a different browser tab**.

[image]

1. Type a higher number on the box and use the **Download Button**. It actually delivers a higher resolution but a lot of wasted space. So Simply type a bigger number.

Here is a screen capture of two segments at 100% exported at 3000px and 6000px. So just cranck the number.

[image]

1. To clear the white space you can use Gimp (I added a segment for that)

### SVG

I am amazed by the program. If you use download it exports black squares and gray lines, and if you open it on a new tab it uses gray squares and dark lines. So download both to choose a style!

1. Use the color combination you like. Rename it as 01.svg for example.
2. Use a pure text editor (not Word). I used Notepad++ because I actually use it but you can use any you have.
3. Copy this line:

   ```
   <img src="01.svg" style="transform: scale(2)">
   ```
4. Change the scale by modifying the number in parenthesis. This scale is dependent on your screen resolution and browser window size.
5. Save the file on the same folder as your image. I saved it as Test.html
6. Open the file on your browser and use a screen capture extension for it. I used Fireshot on Firefox.

Here is a screen capture using the dark lines version.

[image]

It sounds complicated but will take you 5 minutes to do. Once you have installed the plugins and have your basic file, you can simply change the file names.

### Bonus. Crop in Gimp to get a transparent image

1. Open in Gimp.
2. Select >Select by color (Shift+O)
3. Select > Invert (Ctrl+I)
4. Copy
5. File > Create from Clipboard

---

**Original post. I leave it only for consistency for the comments.**

I am assuming the program has limited options when exporting to PNG.

Export as SVG and then use another program to export as PNG at a higher resolution.

Use Inkscape to do that.

But taking a look at the software, just increase the size of the export:

[image]

---

P.S. Any raster image, any, will look pixelated when zooming in, because you are zooming into pixels.

Resizing a low-resolution image, although some algorithms are doing a better job now, will produce smashed potatoes. Producing a high resolution from the start is the best option.

Comment: @javascript_lover - actually this is the correct answer.  Increasing the pixel size creates a higher resolution image. It does not just add more white space.  I tested this. It definitely works.

Comment: Dear Rafael, I have accepted the answer but two things in it confused me; first is "mixing" an Inkscape approach which is far more complex with the mermaid.live tool approach which is far more simple; the second thing and more important thing on which I have even published an entire update chapter in my question post, is that the screenshot you have putted doesn't indicate which "PNG" button to click on, to get a high res version; please go through the last update in my question post to ensure you udnerstand me.

Comment: I updated my answer. As you are a developer, I think you will have no trouble with the SVG updated route.

Comment: Fixed your `<img` problem

Comment: Oh. 8 spaces...

Comment: 4 for indent and 4 for the code in indent

Answer (score 1):

Forget the intelligent PNG upscaling. It will not happen. Forget also exporting as SVG, because the graph generator you use makes utterly complex SVGs. My web browser (=Opera) can show it, but Inkscape cannot. Also Illustrator and Affinity Designer do not show the graph SVG right.  Inkscape even cannot disassemble (ungroup, unclip) it properly for making any fixes. You got some black boxes and I got the same in Inkscape version 1.3.

Export as PDF. Open the PDF in a PDF-aware vector graphics program. Make there as high resolution PNG as you need without including any excessive bitmap image area around the actual drawing.

How? Let the browser show the SVG in a new tab and right click the image. Then one of the options is exporting as PDF. Write a short name for the file to be able to use the file easily, do not accept the long file name that the browser offers.

**Inkscape's** internal import reads the PDF so that the actual image can be dug up.

The fonts are handled poorly, so let Inkscape's internal PDF import convert all texts to curves. That's option "Draw all texts".

Every object in the imported file has a clipping path.They are not good for texts which are not rendered exactly to the right size. Or Mermaid has given unfitting clipping paths. It's better to select all and apply Object > Clip > Release.

You'll get a big black mess, because the clipping paths are filled with black. In addition many of them are in nested (=multilevel) groups. Biggest released clipping paths cover the whole image. Stay calm and ungroup all to be able to remove the black boxes.

Ungrouping must be done several times. You can see in the objects panel if there's still groups. Select all and ungroup until no groups exist. It's far easier to apply Extension > Arrange > Deep Ungroup to get rid of groupings.

Select the black boxes one by one. You cannot select them all for ex. by the same fill color, because texts are also shapes which have black fill. Delete every box after seeing it's not text. There are many of them, because every object has one.

You can see the texts and avoid deleting them because they are rendered a little differently:

[image]

You may think that inserting a colored stroke helps better to see the texts. Yes, it does, but removing that stroke afterwards will be a pain if the graph is complex.

When you have removed the black boxes you can export as PNG. The resolution can be as high as needed and you can have transparent background.

**Adobe Illustrator** handles the PDF much better. There's a clipping mask on every object and some of them do not fit, but releasing them (=select all, apply Object > Clipping Mask > Release) creates shapes which have no fill nor stroke. They can all be selected easily by the sameness. Select one and then apply Select > Same > Fill and Stroke. Pressing DEL removes every clipping mask. Better: In illustrator the texts are still editable texts. And it's well possible that the recent Illustrator also rejects those "on every item" clipping masks automatically. I didn't test it, because in my hobby machine I have only legacy Illustrator.

**Affinity Designer** opens the PDF. It rejects automatically the "on every item" clipping masks. But only those texts are shown right which use an installed font. The embedded font is not used, it's replaced in the PDF import if the exactly same font is not installed.

Comment: Hello and thank you. I am not a graphics designer and basically never worked with Inkscape in my life and some of your advices on Inkspace are unclear to me personally. While I fully agree with you that SVGs by this specific editor are very complex, I don't know what exactly you suggest me to do about it. I ask you in big plea and with all humbleness to try to edit your answer to try to make it more concise and please do include one more screenshot or two if you can.

Comment: I have suggested an edit. You can reject it, approve it, or further edit it or you can have the website's moderators to decide about the suggested edit. Please do work with me together to let the world make Mermaid charts more easily.

Comment: @javascript_lover I rejected the edit, because it suggested unworking procedures.  I rewrote the answer. If the language is bad you can suggest a new edit. I speak a rare tribal language, so my English is far from perfect.

Comment: Thank you for replying fast; nicely but honestly I don't really find an "answer" in the post as it's currently formatted and I'll gladly explain further; it is unclear what is the precise action that you suggest me or anyone with a similar problem to actually do; in other words, there are too many "passages" or too many "moving parts" in the answer; I suggest you to try to narrow it down to a specific solution that should absolutly work to most people.

Comment: @javascript_lover For me it's clear. Because you see SVG and PNG (as it is available) useless get a PDF. Open the PDF in Inkscape or Illustrator, remove the badly implemented clipping masks and make a PNG with a resolution which is as high as the final application needs. That cannot be said simpler. I am not writing any "Inkscape or Illustrator tutorial for greenhorns", I start from the point where the elementary usage of those programs is already known. You can give only one downvote. The rest of the members who do not like tutorials would give 100.

Comment: I certainly like tutorials in fields in which I have no elementary knowledge (like the program Inkscape) and like them even more if they answer a certain question acessible for general audience. Even if could I would probably not downvote, I would have just say the same; a more "algorithm" like type of phrasing is needed; how do you, as an expert, suggest us, general audience to solve it and why. It can be stepped, concise and clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a too long comment. I wonder how it would work in Graphwiz or maybe yEd?

Out of curiosity i made your mermaid chart a graphwiz dot file without labels. You can see a live version [here](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%201%20-%3E%202%3B%0A%20%20%20%202%20-%3E%20A1%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%202%20-%3E%20A2%3B%0A%20%20%20%202%20-%3E%20A3%3B%0A%20%20%20%202%20-%3E%20A4%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20A2%20-%3E%20A%3B%0A%20%20%20%20A1%20-%3E%205%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20A2%20-%3E%205%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%205%20-%3E%20A5%3B%0A%20%20%20%20A4%20-%3E%20A5%3B%0A%20%20%20%205%20-%3E%206%0A%20%20%20%206%20-%3E%207%0A%20%20%20%208%20-%3E%209%0A%20%20%20%20X%20-%3E%2011%3B%0A%20%20%20%207%20-%3E%2010%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%207%20-%3E11%3B%0A%20%20%20%207%20-%3E%2012%3B%0A%20%20%20%207%20-%3E%2014%3B%0A%20%20%20%2012%20-%3E%20B%3B%0A%20%20%20%20XX%20-%3E%20B%3B%0A%20%20%20%2011%20-%3E%2013%3B%0A%20%20%20%2012%20-%3E%2013%3B%0A%20%20%20%209%20-%3E%2013%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%2011%20-%3E%2015%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20XX%20-%3E%2015%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%2010%20-%3E%2016%3B%0A%20%20%20%2015%20-%3E%2016%3B%0A%20%20%20%2013%20-%3E%2017%3B%0A%20%20%20%2017%20-%3E%2018%3B%0A%20%20%20%2017%20-%3E%2019%3B%0A%20%20%20%2017%20-%3E%2020%3B%0A%20%20%20%2017%20-%3E%2021%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%2015%20-%3E%20C1%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%2018%20-%3E%20C1%3B%0A%20%20%20%2021%20-%3E%20C1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C1%20-%3E%20C2%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20C2%20-%3E%20C2_1%3B%0A%20%20%20%2016%20-%3E%20C2_1%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20XXX%20-%3E%20C3%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C2%20-%3E%20C3%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C3%20-%3E%20C4%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C4%20-%3E%20C2_1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C4%20-%3E%20C5%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C4%20-%3E%20C6%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20A4%20-%3E%20XXXX%3B%0A%20%20%20%2016%20-%3E%20XXXX%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C3%20-%3E%20XXXX%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20B%20-%3E%20I1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20XX%20-%3E%20I1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20XXXX%20-%3E%20I1%3B%0A%20%20%20%2016%20-%3E%20I1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C4%20-%3E%20I1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I1%20-%3E%20I2%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I1%20-%3E%20I3%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I2%20-%3E%20I2_2%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I2%20-%3E%20I2_1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I2_2%20-%3E%20I3%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20I2_2%20-%3E%20I5%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I3%20-%3E%20I4%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I4%20-%3E%20I5%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I3%20-%3E%20I6%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I6%20-%3E%20I7%3B%0A%20%20%20%2017%20-%3E%20C7%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C1%20-%3E%20C7%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C5%20-%3E%20C7%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C6%20-%3E%20C7%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%2015%20-%3E%20ZZ%3B%0A%20%20%20%2015%20-%3E%20I2%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20I2%20-%3E%20I8%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I2%20-%3E%20I8%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20I6%20-%3E%20I8%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I2%20-%3E%20I9%3B%0A%20%20%20%20I7%20-%3E%20E%3B%0A%20%20%20%2017%20-%3E%20C8%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C5%20-%3E%20C8%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C7%20-%3E%20C8%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C7%20-%3E%20C9%3B%0A%20%20%20%20C8%20-%3E%20R1%3B%0A%20%20%20%2019%20-%3E%20R1%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D), code below in case link dies:

```
digraph G {


    1;
    1 -> 2;
    2 -> A1; 
    2 -> A2;
    2 -> A3;
    2 -> A4;

    A2 -> A;
    A1 -> 5; 
    A2 -> 5;
    

    5 -> A5;
    A4 -> A5;
    5 -> 6
    6 -> 7
    8 -> 9
    X -> 11;
    7 -> 10; 
    7 ->11;
    7 -> 12;
    7 -> 14;
    12 -> B;
    XX -> B;
    11 -> 13;
    12 -> 13;
    9 -> 13;
    
    11 -> 15; 
    XX -> 15;
    
    
    10 -> 16;
    15 -> 16;
    13 -> 17;
    17 -> 18;
    17 -> 19;
    17 -> 20;
    17 -> 21;

    15 -> C1; 
    18 -> C1;
    21 -> C1;
    C1 -> C2;

    C2 -> C2_1;
    16 -> C2_1;

    XXX -> C3;
    C2 -> C3;
    C3 -> C4;
    C4 -> C2_1;
    C4 -> C5;
    C4 -> C6;

    A4 -> XXXX;
    16 -> XXXX;
    C3 -> XXXX;
    
    B -> I1;
    XX -> I1;
    XXXX -> I1;
    16 -> I1;
    C4 -> I1;
    I1 -> I2;
    I1 -> I3;
    I2 -> I2_2;
    I2 -> I2_1;
    I2_2 -> I3; 
    I2_2 -> I5;
    I3 -> I4;
    I4 -> I5;
    I3 -> I6;
    I6 -> I7;
    17 -> C7;
    C1 -> C7;
    C5 -> C7;
    C6 -> C7;
    
    15 -> ZZ;
    15 -> I2; 
    I2 -> I8;
    I2 -> I8; 
    I6 -> I8;
    I2 -> I9;
    I7 -> E;
    17 -> C8;
    C5 -> C8;
    C7 -> C8;
    C7 -> C9;
    C8 -> R1;
    19 -> R1;

}
```

And obligatory result image:

[image]